# Implementing URL rewriting with wamp and php

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wampserver

I can't implement URL rewriting.

What I've done so far:

**1.** Enabled `rewrite_module` in apache.

**2.** Added a `.htaccess` file to my website (test) in the directory:

127.0.0.1/test/

which contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/news/([0-9]+)\.html /news.php?news_id=$1
```

**3.** I have a `news.php` file which contains

```
echo "hello world";
```

Now, whenever I go to URL: `http://127.0.0.1/news/1`, I get a

> 'Page not found'

Answer (score 0):

I was successful in the following.

Files:

```
document_root/
|- .htaccess
|- news.php
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule news/([0-9]+)\.html news\.php?news_id=$1
```

http://127.0.0.1/news/1.html
 -> hello world

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you've successfully enabled the rewrite module (`rewrite_module`) of your Apache server, and that you've put your `.htaccess` file inside the `test` directory which is in the root directory of your web server ( like for example : `c:\wamp\www\test`).

So here we have 2 cases of what (I suppose) you want to do :

- 1. Access to your URL using, for example : `http://127.0.0.1/test/news/1.html`.
- 2. Access to your URL using, for example : `http://127.0.0.1/news/1.html`.

---

So, for the 1st case, you have just to edit your `.htaccess` file like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)\.html news.php?news_id=$1
```

Here any URL like `http://127.0.0.1/test/news/1.html` will be rewriting to `test\news.php` and pass to it the `news_id` param.

---

And for the 2nd case, you have to put your `.htaccess` file into the web server root directory and add just the [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase) directive

> The RewriteBase directive specifies the URL prefix to be used for per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule directives that substitute a relative path.

so your `.htaccess` will be like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)\.html news.php?news_id=$1
```

Of course you can find many many tutorials on the net about how to rewrite toyr URLs using the `.htaccess` file ...

Hope that can help.